# Do not create new order until paid by points in shopify?

Tags: javascript, shopify, liquid

So what I'm trying to do here is "Skip the creation of order unless & until customer pay by their loyalty points from external website" Once they redirect from shopify to external website where customer fill all the loyalty details & after the success json response from external website then only create the order.

Current Flow Explained in my shopify website.

1. Customer add items to the cart
2. Customer then go to the checkout page fill all the personal information and select the payment method as "My custom loyalty"
3. At last customer click on "Complete Order" button on checkout page.
   [image]
4. I have a additional script which will redirect customer to loyalty website.

Now, the problem after step 3) customer order has been created. So even if customer did not paid through loyalty program his order has been created.
Order processing below screen shouldn't be executed when customer click on "complete order" button.
[image]

My additional script:

```
document.location.href="https://loyalltywebsite.com/payment";
```